# How to set frame to UIBUTTON based on device type?

Tags: ios7

I want set frame to UIButton based on device like 5,6,6plus,i tried with below code but i am getting trouble with 6plus,for 6,6plus same method (IS_IPHONE_6_6PLUS)is getting called,what,s the wrong with my code please let me know.

```
#define IS_IPHONE_6_6PLUS  ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height >= 667)?TRUE:FALSE
#define IS_IPHONE6PLUS  ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width >= 414)?TRUE:FALSE
#define IS_IPHONE_4  ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 480)?TRUE:FALSE
#define IS_IPHONE_5 ( fabs( ( double )[ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.height - ( double )568 ) < DBL_EPSILON )


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
if (IS_IPHONE_5)
     {
        loginview.frame = CGRectMake(108, 393, 35, 35);
        _signInButton.frame=CGRectMake(173,393, 35,35);
     }
     else if (IS_IPHONE_6_6PLUS)
     {
         loginview.frame = CGRectMake(128, 476, 35, 35);
         _signInButton.frame=CGRectMake(208,476, 35,35);

     }
     else if (IS_IPHONE6PLUS)
     {

         loginview.frame = CGRectMake(118, 506, 35, 35);
         _signInButton.frame=CGRectMake(163,506, 35,35);

     }
}
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know exactly how you have define the size of devices. I think it is wrong i am Defining size of different devices like this:-

```
#define IS_IPAD (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
#define IS_IPHONE (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
#define IS_RETINA ([[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] >= 2.0)

//--Use main screen to check screen height and width
#define SCREEN_WIDTH ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width)
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height)
#define SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH (MAX(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))
#define SCREEN_MIN_LENGTH (MIN(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))

//--Defining Length According to size of different Devices
#define IS_IPHONE_4_OR_LESS (IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH < 568.0)
#define IS_IPHONE_5 (IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 568.0)
#define IS_IPHONE_6 (IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 667.0)
#define IS_IPHONE_6P (IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 736.0)
```

now you can set your button's (x,y,width,height) to set it in different devices.

Like:-

```
    if(IS_IPHONE_4_OR_LESS)
    {
        //set your button according to iphone 4
       //Your button looks in iphone 4 or less
    }
    if(IS_IPHONE_5)
    {
        //set your button according to iphone 5
       //Your button looks in iphone 5 
    }
    if(IS_IPHONE_6)
    {
        //set your button according to iphone 6
       //Your button looks in iphone 6
    }
    if(IS_IPHONE_6P)
    {
        //set your button according to iphone 6 plus
       //Your button looks in iphone 6 plus
    }
```

**Note:-**

It also include size of **iphone and ipad** both. so, you can use it with making **constant file** and just **import** it in your **view controller** and use same as above..

Comment: How will you handle screen resolutions of dual view iPads? New iPads?
Handling screen resolutions on a case by case way is a dead end.

Comment: you can get size of ipad with this `#define IS_IPAD (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)` and set according to your requirement in conditions.

Comment: That was not the point. The point is that handling screen resolutions on a case by case way will eventually get your app not to work correctly on some device and screen resolution you can't possibly know today.

Answer (score 0):

If your purpose is just making sure that on @3x devices and @2x devices "thin lines" remain thin, i.e. one pixel wide, you are doing it wrong and unnecessarily complicated.

Just load @3x. @2x image versions as resources in your app.
You should not try to infere and handle screen size by code.
- New devices with unexpected screen sizes will break your app.
- Your app won't run correctly in new unexpected screen sizes (think dual view multitasking on newer iPads).